Implementing triangular ramp in simulation
I am using the UCC256301 in a project (I know it says it is not recommended for new designs). I am trying to simulate my system using PLECS and it needs the controller IC's behaviour implemented. From the datasheet's block diagram (Fig.28 below) there is a triggered compensating ramp added to the sensed capacitor voltage.
To simulate this in PLECS, I have tried using c-script but didn't get it right, a block form using switches triggered by the low and high-side MOSFET gate signals feeding into an integrator block to get up and down ramps, and I also tried manipulating the triangle wave generator block available in the library.
So far none of these have worked. Anyone can help?


The solution that finally worked is exactly as mentioned on the datasheet. I used a controlled current source element that was fed by a 1 or a -1 constant triggered by the high side switch gate. In PLECS, the current source replicates the waveform it is supplied by, so in this case, 1 A source or sink. Connect a capacitor in series to get the desired current ramp magnitude.
If the rest of the simulation model is implemented correctly, the duty cycle is automatically 50% as it should be in LLC converters.
